# strange � sign in html text

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a very strange problem...

Inside a wordpress website i have this � sign when text are finished...

you can see it [here](http://geulahvod.com/category/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94-he/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99-he-he/) in the left square.

Screenshot attached [here](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/917307/64d37065fa7e49f94c263ca8ffa80635) to make its more clear.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382524/all-is-on-utf8-but-i-still-got-strange-char-like

Answer (score 2):

ok - finally i understand that its because the substr() php function...
and in utf-8 you need to use the mb_substr() function like this:

```
<?php
        $utf8string = "cakeæøå";
        echo mb_substr($utf8string,0,5,'UTF-8');
?>
```

and NOT like this:

```
<?php
           $utf8string = "cakeæøå";
           echo substr($utf8string,0,5);
?>
```

from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#90581) comment

Answer (score 0):

By above solution you will get rid of only for this text but think if same problem on more variables.

Please define character encoding scheme as below in the header.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Please find more details at below:-
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: add this :<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> didn't fix the problem...

Comment: please read the given url, you will find answer. Here all the details are provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer but that's not the point...the website has the <meta charset="UTF-8"> tag and that's something with mb_substr function as i wrote above

Comment: you can check database column collation type and need to change this to utf8_general_ci .